# Nasted List without shrinkwrap (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

Take a look at these examples first,

```
class Example1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: x,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const Text('parent'),
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: x,
            itemBuilder: (_, i) => const Text('Child'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

................................................................

```
class Example2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example2(this.data, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Data data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(data.name),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (_, i) => Example2(data.subData[i]),
            childCount: data.length,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Using **shrinkwrap** true or **Expanded** will build all widgets at a time. But it will affect performance. So, any way to avoid shrinkwrap to unusual build of widgets?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the SliverList and CustomScrollView. Using this widgets you can have nested list and not affect the performance. this is a little example

```html
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black87),    
                child: Center(child: Text('Este es el ejemplo de una lista anidada', style: GoogleFonts.adventPro(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),))),
            ElementTile(currentNumber: 2),
            ElementTile(currentNumber: 3)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) => ElementTile(currentNumber: index)))
  ],
),
```

Remember use ListView.builder in the first Sliver, when you have many elements to render.
I hope this info help you.
Repo: https://github.com/FlutterMedellinMeetup/flutter-apprentice/blob/main/cuarta_clase/examples/widgets/ListGridAndOthers/example/lib/list_examples/nested_listviews.dart